# How does referencing a class instance inside constructor work?

Tags: java

```
class Test{

    int x;

    Test(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

When we say `this.x = x` the constructor hasn't been completed yet, so no object is created so how does `this` actually refer to an object that hasn't been created yet?

Comment: *"the constructor hasn't been completed yet, so no object is created"* says who?

Comment: An object is created when a call to one of the constructors of the class is made. That doesn't mean that it is the constructor itself that creates the object. This is quite a nonsensical discussion anyway. The language is just an abstraction; in reality its all just bytecode.

Comment: The first line of a parameterized constructor is always a call to super();  If you don't make a call to super. that call it is made for you.  From then on you have an object.  And in this case, lexically int x has been created for you already.  Move int x; below the constructor and compare, I'm pretty sure you will get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor is really more of an initializer than anything. When you call a constructor:

```
Test t = new Test(3);
```

it's the `new` keyword that actually allocates/creates the space in memory, and then calls the constructor to *build the object* within that memory, initializing fields and placing memory wherever it needs to be. That's all abstracted away behind the setting of fields, which is what we usually do in the constructor.